# How is IntelliJ IDEA an executable (.exe) if it's a Java program running in the JVM?

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm, jetbrains-ide

I've heard that IntelliJ products (most of them at least) are developed via Java / Kotlin and run in the JVM. In one instance, I have observed IDEA and CLion throwing Java Exceptions, which does confirm the fact that these run via the JVM runtime. However, how are they packaged in an executable instead of a JAR file?

I've tried to look for resources around this, but I cannot find any clear methodologies and justifications as to how they did it or why did it in the first place. Any clues?

Comment: I suppose you could find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file